# Trigger a drush @sites cr --yes daily

Tags: 8, drush, caching

Drupal 8.

Title sums up pretty much my question.

I'm wondering what is the best way to rebuild all my site's cache daily.

A cron job with Truncate table cache ?
Module who rebuild cache on each site ?

Does a plugin exist?

Comment: are you interested on all caches? or just website page caches for anonymous users?

Comment: Website caches for anonymous users.

Comment: Why you would do such thing?

Comment: @sanzante For an unknown reason, sometimes some "blocks" disappear from Anonymous user's view and if a flush cache it comes back so I figure that cache should be flush at least once a week. What do you think ?

Comment: I think you should investigate block disappearing. Cache does a good job keeping your site fast and responsive. Those blocks disappearing indicate a problem that could be impacting others parts of your application but you didn't notice yet.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is a cron job that calls `drush @alias cr` set for 24 hours. You can do that at the server level.

Comment: OK good. How do I do that ? What kind of cron job? Only cron job I know is the one you set in cpanel with a php file.

Comment: @Simon Go to CPanel. Create a new job. Add `/path/to/drush @alias cr --yes` as the file to be executed. Set your frequency. You can get `/path/to/drush` running `which drush`.

Comment: OK. Since im on Windows server, I created a scheduled Task to run drush @sites cr --yes and it seems be working but its really slow. Task is currently running since more than 2 hours.. and when I use cmd it took around 30 min. Not sure if its possible to do it that way.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe drush @sites cr --yes in my site folder

Answer (score 0):

Since the question focuses on website page caching for anonymous users, the case for Drupal 8 is quite simple:

> Drupal 8 provides an Internal Page Cache module that is recommended
>   for small to medium-sized websites. This core module, which is enabled
>   by default, caches pages for anonymous users.

You don't need to do anything, apart from defining the expire duration of your caches for browsers and (reverse) proxies.

Most importantly:

> The page cache in Drupal 8 is instantly updated when something has
>   changed.

Source: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/administering-a-drupal-8-site/internal-page-cache

Hope that covers the OP, good luck!